# getting null xml from url

Tags: android, xml, web-services, http

i am trying to get an xml output from a url but i am getting a null xml in return. But,if i try to execute that url on browser its getting me response...here is my code

```
    signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            String us = username.getText().toString();
            String na = name.getText().toString();
            String pa = password.getText().toString();
            String rep = repass.getText().toString();
            String e = email.getText().toString();

            if (us.equals("") || na.equals("") || pa.equals("")
                    || rep.equals("") || e.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fill All Entries",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                if (pa.equals(rep)) {
                    // xml_ajax_register(us, na, pa, e);
                    String url = "http://localhost:9090/plugins/userService/userservice?type="
                            + "add&secret=0LRF2i8I&username="
                            + us
                            + "&password="
                            + pa
                            + "&name="
                            + na
                            + "&email="
                            + e;
                    System.out.println("URL IS "+url);
                    String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(url);
                    // Document doc=parser.getDomElement(xml);
                    //
                    // NodeList nl=doc.getElementsByTagName("result");

                    System.out.println("XML Is " + xml);

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "PassWord Doesn't Match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                            .show();

                }

            }

            // String xml = getXmlFromUrl(url);

        }

    });
```

and my xml parser class is

```
    public class XMLParser {

// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Maybe there is an exception occurring in your XML loading code, but due to the way you handle exceptions it returns null. You just print the stack traces, but this leaves xml to null.

Comment: Do you see any output from your print?

Comment: Yes,my String xml returns null on my output

Comment: can you run your code in debug mode? and see where are you encountering null pointer exception. It could be anywhere, may be at us, na, pa res, e. Are you sure, you are forming url properly before calling parser.getXmlFromUrl(url), can you confirm that...